# How to use Amination in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

So when I try something like this

```
batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(timeEllapsed, true), 0, 0);
```

I get an error because draw only takes a Texture or Texture Region Object, but animation.getKeyFrame(float, boolean) returns an Object, and can't be cast to either of those other Objects. I am making a game for an OOP class, but I can't find any current tutorials on LibGdx and the framework has seemed to change since a few years ago.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recent change in LibGDX, so tutorials may be outdated.

Animation is now generic so it can support animation frame types of any kind, not just TextureRegions.

To use it with TextureRegions, declare the type:

```
public Animation<TextureRegion> myAnimation;

//...

myAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

So to make animations , you are going to need these following variables:

1. TextureAtlas
2. TextureRegion
3. int currentFrame = 1;
4. int maxFrame = 2;

Note: You must have a TextureAtlas and your png file imported in your project.

Now initialize the texture atlas and the texture region.

```
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("animation.atlas"));
    region = new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("0001"));
    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setPosition(100,300);
```

## Changing the image, hence animating

This is the part where real animation is happening

```
        currentFrame++;
        if(currentFrame>MAX_FRAME){
            currentFrame = 1;
        }
        sprite.setRegion(atlas.findRegion(String.format("%04d", currentFrame)));
```

If you want your image to channge , say every 0.2 sec you can also do that like:

Create a variable timeFactor;

```
        timeFactor+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(timeFactor>=0.2f){
            currentFrame++;
            if(currentFrame>MAX_FRAME){
                currentFrame = 1;
            }
            sprite.setRegion(atlas.findRegion(String.format("%04d", currentFrame)));
            timeFactor= 0;
        }
```